# Implementatnion of std::vector::push_back in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

I explore msvc 2013 STL implementation and found this implemantation of std::vector::push_back:

```
void push_back(const value_type& _Val)
    {   // insert element at end
    if (_Inside(_STD addressof(_Val))) // <-- is this check really necessary?
        {   // push back an element
        size_type _Idx = _STD addressof(_Val) - this->_Myfirst;
        if (this->_Mylast == this->_Myend)
            _Reserve(1);
        this->_Getal().construct(this->_Mylast,
            this->_Myfirst[_Idx]);
        ++this->_Mylast;
        }
    else
        {   // push back a non-element
        if (this->_Mylast == this->_Myend)
            _Reserve(1);
        this->_Getal().construct(this->_Mylast,
            _Val);
        ++this->_Mylast;
        }
    }
```

And I have a question: is check

> if (_Inside(_STD addressof(_Val)))

really neccessary? This condition checks is _Val belongs to this vector or not. For example this condition is true in cases like:

```
std::vector<int> v(1);
v.push_back(v[0]);
```

What the difference between push_back of element of same vector and other values?

Comment: haven't you already answered your own question?

Comment: No, as I see in both cases we have the same code, is there any sense in this check?

Comment: @user3290628: After `_Reserve(1)`, `_val` is no longer a valid reference.

Comment: it's not quite the same code. in the one case, element that is with this vector, the old value is accessed via the copy possibly made via buffer reallocation. in the other case, just some value, it's accessed directly.

Comment: Is there something equivalent for the other vector modification operations in the MS implementation?

Comment: @Deduplicator this check I see only in push_back(...) and resize()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if that extra check is mandated by the standard, but it avoids a subtle bug that can happen if you push into a vector an element of itself.

Suppose you do, as in your example,

```
std::vector<int> v(1);
v.push_back(v[0]);
```

in an implementation that doesn't do that check. Now, if the vector's capacity is more than 1, all is fine and good, `v[0]` is just copy-constructed in the correct position.

But what happens if the vector has to reallocate? In that case, the reference to `v[0]` that was passed to `push_back` gets invalidated just after the reallocation, so `push_back` will try to copy inside the vector an object that no longer exists.

The code in the implementation you posted avoids the problem by checking if the reference points to an element inside the vector, and, in that case, it takes note of its index. After the reallocation, even if the reference is invalidated, the index is still correct, so the copy can be performed without risks.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Probably that the implementation be done this way. I can imagine a different implementation that doesn't require this as a special case.

Comment: @KerrekSB: clarified. IIRC other implementations didn't have such a check and failed if you pushed an element of the vector in itself. I don't remember if that was an implementation bug or if it was actually not requested by the standard.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Hm, it just sounds weird: "it's not mandated, but it avoids a subtle bug"... isn't it understood that a conforming implementation have no bugs? (Nothing in the standard says that `v.push_back(v.back())` is not required to work.)

Comment: You mean it papers over a possible bug in the callers code.

Comment: AFAICS there is no language in the standard that adds a precondition that the new item reference must not be inside the vector. Hence the vector implementation is required to handle that correctly. I think this is a good case for move semantics, how if `std::vector` was designed *now* it would not have that by-reference argument.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I don't know, I was perplexed by the fact that the standard says that it takes the argument by `const` reference *and* invalidates all the references. Again, I don't take a precise position on this issue, it just seems a bit confused to me.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I find that last point questionable. Just because it is now *possible* to design efficiently movable types doesn't mean that a standard library container should flat-out *require* such types in order to be vaguely efficient. It seems pretty sane to accept the pushable value by reference. This is a good example how in a quality library, you shouldn't optimize for the library writer's convenience, but for the value provided to the consumer.

Comment: @KerrekSB: one could just have a suitably named (or distinguished by argument) by-reference adder method, leaving the default efficient and nice for movable types and basic types. Pessimization = ungood. Yes? :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I don't follow. Passing by value is always worse than passing by reference. Passing by value is OK for convenient, readable user code, but there's no reason why a core library component should pay such a completely avoidable cost.

Comment: @KerrekSB: no, passing by value can be most efficient when the value ends up being stored somewhere, and is movable, or small. for the case where it's stored, it's only non-movable large values that suffer. and for those, the idea of client code responsibility, to then use dedicated by-reference method.

Comment: Thanks for you and Kerrek SB for you explanation. But now I have another question (I updated initial question).

Comment: @user3290628: being that, as you said, another problem, you should post it in a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

The code in the two code paths is blatantly different:

```
construct(this->_Mylast, this->_Myfirst[_Idx])
```

Compared to:

```
construct(this->_Mylast, _Val)
```

The reason is of course that if the vector's capacity is exhausted, it needs to reallocate its storage, which invalidates references.

If the argument, `_Val`, is not part of the vector, then that has no relevance, but if it *is*, then we can no longer use it after reallocating. So in the first code path, where `_Val` is part of the vector, the value is referred to by its vector index rather than by the original function argument.